# Objective C Core Plot Area

Tags: objective-c, ios6, core-plot

I have a Core Plot scatter plot up and running, and I was looking to see if it were possible to fill the enclosed areas with a certain color...can anyone point me in the write direction?

Thank you.

Best...SL

Comment: did this help?  Was is what you were looking for?  Let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out core plot's website.  They have a bunch of sample apps.  If you want to fill in the area under the curve, you want to check out the gradient fill demo.  Hope this helps.
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/